# oracle histogram return wrong cardinality

Tags: oracle, performance, histogram

i have this subquery as a part of bigger query:

```
SELECT *
from   totals a
where  A.COMPANY       ='TTT'
AND    A.LOGISTIC_COMP = '111'.
```

this table has ~32M rows, and the count of the rows in this query, with those parameters return ~9M rows.

i saw that with different parameters (company, logistic_company) i got different performance.

i checked and found that there is big distribution on this columns,
and it cause the optimizer to estimate the cardinality wrong.

so i create an histograms on that columns using this statement:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS  ('MY_SCHEMA', 'TOTALS',METHOD_OPT    => 'FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 1 FOR COLUMNS company size 254, logistic_comp size 254');
```

but even after that - the cardinality stay wrong!

the optimizer thinks that there are ~2.5M rows instead of ~9M.

the index that the plan use (with this cardinality) is up to date..

is that make sense?

Answer (score 4):

Most probably your columns are correlated. Oracle was not able to compute stats on two columns. You can create stats for pair of columns. It is called **Extended statistics**

As described in this [link.](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/extended_statistics). On background Oracle will create invisible virtual column, which represents concatenation of COMPANY and LOGISTIC_COMP.

You also should check estimated cardinalities with real ones by using the hint [GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS.](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/how_do_i_know_if)

- Create extended stats

  ```
  SELECT DBMS_STATS.CREATE_EXTENDED_STATS(null, 'TOTALS', '(COMPANY,LOGISTIC_COMP)') 
  FROM DUAL;
  ```
- Execute the query using GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS hint

  ```
  SELECT /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ *
  from   totals a
  where  A.COMPANY       = 'TTT'
  AND    A.LOGISTIC_COMP = '111';
  ```
- Check A-ctual vs. E-stimated cardinalities

  ```
  SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(NULL, NULL, 'ALLSTATS LAST'));
  ```

PS: Since version 12c Oracle creates these extended stats on column sets by its own.